# Does the Bible solve an NP-hard problem?

Tags: np-complete

In the Bible, a census is taken of the 12 tribes of Israel:

Simeon: 59,300
Levi: 22,000
Judah: 74,600
Issachar: 54,400
Joseph: 72,700
Benjamin: 35,400
Reuben: 46,500
Gad: 45,650
Asher: 41,500
Zebulun: 57,400
Dan: 62,700
Naphtali: 53,400

In the book of Deuteronomy 27: 12-13, the tribes are partitioned into two groups, the first group consisting of Simeon, Levi, Judah, Issachar, Joseph, Benjamin, and the second group consisting of Reuben, Gad, Asher, Zebulun, Dan, Naphtali.

Someone mentioned to me that this particular partition is the optimal in the sense that it minimizes the absolute value of the total number of people in the first group minus the total number of people in the second group. This partition problem is an NP-hard problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem

Is this calculation correct?

Comment: "Check my answer" questions are off-topic. It's hard to see how "check somebody else's answer" questions could be on-topic. And your title is misleading: solving a single instance of an **NP**-hard problem is not the same as solving the problem.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, it's not my answer. And I can't see how the title is misleading at all. If the Bible solves this instance of Partition, then the Bible solves an NP-hard problem, since Partition is NP-hard.

Comment: My point is that *all* answer-checking problems are off-topic. It doesn't matter if the answer is yours or somebody else's. As for "solving NP-hard problems", is the Boolean formula $X$ satisfiable? Is the one-vertex graph 3-colourable? Great! We can all solve single instances of NP-complete problems.

Comment: But every question is an answer-checking problem, by definition.

Comment: Solving an _instance_ of an NP-hard problem is not the same as solving an NP-hard problem. The latter requires being able to solve all instances in polynomial time.

Comment: "Is this really true?": what is really true ? That the Bible mentions the partition ? That the partition is optimal in the min-abs sense ? That the partition problem is NP-hard ? That someone mentioned it to you ? ...

Comment: @Craig: solving this problem by hand would take less than a week's work. No miracle.

Comment: I'm not claiming that this would be a miracle if it were solved.

Comment: Finding a fish is not the same as learning to fish. The former will
feed you only for a day. Similarly the Bible did not solve an NP-hard
problem. At best it solved an instance of a NP-hard problem. But since
any trivial problem can be construed as an instance of a NP-hard
problem, this could almost be interpreted as a derogatory statement
about the Bible.

Comment: @mhum Are you sure about your second sentence? I would remove the last
3 words.

Comment: @babou Well, I guess that when I say "solve", I'm actually implying "solve in polynomial time" which is the context I inferred from the asker's question. If instead "solve" was intended to mean "find a solution", brute force enumeration would be sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The partition provided in that passage is not optimal:

(Simeon + Levi + Judah + Issachar + Joseph + Benjamin) - (Reuben + Gad + Asher + Zebulun + Dan + Naphtali) = 318400 - 307150 = 11250

(Asher + Benjamin + Joseph + Reuben + Simeon + Zebulun) - (Dan + Gad + Issachar + Judah + Levi + Naphtali) = 312800 - 312750 = 50

Comment: I got the same result. Indeed the bible did not solve an optimisation problem. Even if they had, it wouldn't mean anything - they may well have brute forced it. (only need to check 4096 possibilities)

Comment: Naturally, I also brute-forced it. Given how few possibilities there were to check, I'd wonder why anyone would even claim that original partition was optimal (in the sense given by the asker).

Comment: It seems the asker did not know how to verify themselves. And, if I may, this kind of bombastic, fallacious mathematical or scientific claim is quite common among certain religious circles.

Comment: I just heard a rabbi say that one of his congregants told him this.

Comment: It is possible that they didn't use the tribe of Levi in the count, as this tribe isn't counted like the other tribes. But your answer is correct.

Comment: If Levi is excluded, the optimal partition is obtained by (Benjamin+Asher+Gad+Zeubulun+Simeon+Dan) - (Reuben+Naphtali+Issachar+Joseph+Judah) = 301950 - 301600 = 350.